# ::before clickable icon

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make the link icon in my code clickable so that the user can click anywhere in the card to go to another page. I've tried (" attr(href) ") but that added the URL text next to the icon which I don't want. Is this something that is possible? Other posts I've read mentioned it was a bug. Is that still the case?

```css
:root {
    --secondary-color: #4b4945;
    --light-text-color: #fafafa;
    --dark-text-color: #37332f;
    --norm-text-color: #4b4945;
    --bg-med: #efefef;
    --primary-color: #492365;
    --primary-header: #492365;
    --solid-button-text: #fafafa;
    --solid-button-text-hover: #120919;
    --hollow-button-text: #120919;
    --primary-lighter-1: #5b3974;
    --primary-lighter-2: #6a4b81;
    --primary-lighter-3: #a491b2;
    --primary-lighter-4: #d2c8d9;
    --primary-lighter-5: #e4dee8;
    --primary-lighter-6: #ede9f0;
    --primary-darker-1: #42205b;
    --primary-darker-2: #371a4c;
    --primary-darker-3: #251233;
    --primary-darker-4: #120919;
    --hover-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #492365;
    --border-color: #492365;
    --banner-overlay: rgba(73, 35, 101, 0.65);
    --inset-shadow: none;
    --outset-shadow: none;
    --flat-border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
    max-width: 80rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.card {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #492365;
    background-color: #492365;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: var(--flat-border);
    border-color: var(--border-color);
    box-shadow: var(--outset-shadow);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    margin: 0;
}

.card>p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card>p:last-of-type.card__title {
    margin: 0;
}

.card__image {
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

.card__image>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.card__image.--icon {
    background-color: #492365;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.card__content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.card__content>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.card__content>p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card__title {
    background-color: #492365 !important;
    color: #fafafa !important;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem !important;
    background-color: var(--primary-color) !important;
    color: var(--solid-button-text) !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.card__buttons {
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card__buttons>.button {
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.card.--linked>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.card.--linked:hover,
.card.--linked:focus-within {
    transition: transform 0.05s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(73, 35, 101, 0.9);
    box-shadow: var(--hover-shadow);
}

@media only screen and (hover: none) {
    .card.--linked::before {
        content: "\1F517";
        background-color: #492365;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-family: "foundation-icons";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: var(--solid-button-text);
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        opacity: 0.9;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: -5rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0em) {
    .card.--linked::before {
        content: "\1F517";
        background-color: #492365;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-family: "foundation-icons";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: var(--solid-button-text);
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        opacity: 0.9;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: -5rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

.card.--linked[data-pseudo-text]::before {
    content: attr(data-pseudo-text);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    .card.--linked.--pseudo-none::before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card --linked">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
      <h2 class="card__title">title</h2>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quasi aut deleniti, nisi quo cum, repellendus eius sint consectetur exercitationem aliquid eveniet, eligendi natus neque distinctio omnis consequatur a hic?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @David The snippet shows you can click anywhere in the card _except_ on the icon. I'm guessing OP wants the icon to be clickable, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you assign the classes `card --linked` to the `<a>` element (one level deeper):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="card --linked" data-pseudo-text="link">
      <h2 class="card__title">title</h2>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quasi aut deleniti, nisi quo cum, repellendus eius sint consectetur exercitationem aliquid eveniet, eligendi natus neque distinctio omnis consequatur a hic?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, of course, it would help if you also defined the `data-pseudo-text` attribute in the same `<a>` element:

```css
:root {
    --secondary-color: #4b4945;
    --light-text-color: #fafafa;
    --dark-text-color: #37332f;
    --norm-text-color: #4b4945;
    --bg-med: #efefef;
    --primary-color: #492365;
    --primary-header: #492365;
    --solid-button-text: #fafafa;
    --solid-button-text-hover: #120919;
    --hollow-button-text: #120919;
    --primary-lighter-1: #5b3974;
    --primary-lighter-2: #6a4b81;
    --primary-lighter-3: #a491b2;
    --primary-lighter-4: #d2c8d9;
    --primary-lighter-5: #e4dee8;
    --primary-lighter-6: #ede9f0;
    --primary-darker-1: #42205b;
    --primary-darker-2: #371a4c;
    --primary-darker-3: #251233;
    --primary-darker-4: #120919;
    --hover-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #492365;
    --border-color: #492365;
    --banner-overlay: rgba(73, 35, 101, 0.65);
    --inset-shadow: none;
    --outset-shadow: none;
    --flat-border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
    max-width: 80rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.card {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #492365;
    background-color: #492365;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: var(--flat-border);
    border-color: var(--border-color);
    box-shadow: var(--outset-shadow);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    margin: 0;
}

.card>p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card>p:last-of-type.card__title {
    margin: 0;
}

.card__image {
    background-color: #fefefe;
}

.card__image>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.card__image.--icon {
    background-color: #492365;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.card__content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.card__content>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.card__content>p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card__title {
    background-color: #492365 !important;
    color: #fafafa !important;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem !important;
    background-color: var(--primary-color) !important;
    color: var(--solid-button-text) !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.card__buttons {
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card__buttons>.button {
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.card.--linked>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.card.--linked:hover,
.card.--linked:focus-within {
    transition: transform 0.05s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.01, 1.01);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(73, 35, 101, 0.9);
    box-shadow: var(--hover-shadow);
}

@media only screen and (hover: none) {
    .card.--linked::before {
        content: "\1F517";
        background-color: #492365;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-family: "foundation-icons";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: var(--solid-button-text);
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        opacity: 0.9;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: -5rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0em) {
    .card.--linked::before {
        content: "\1F517";
        background-color: #492365;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-family: "foundation-icons";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: var(--solid-button-text);
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        opacity: 0.9;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: -5rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

.card.--linked { text-decoration:none; }
.card.--linked::before {
    content: attr(data-pseudo-text);
    background-color: red;
}

@mmedia only screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    .card.--linked.--pseudo-none::before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="card --linked" data-pseudo-text="this is your pseudo text">
      <h2 class="card__title">title</h2>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quasi aut deleniti, nisi quo cum, repellendus eius sint consectetur exercitationem aliquid eveniet, eligendi natus neque distinctio omnis consequatur a hic?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A simple `.card.--linked { text-decoration:none; }` in the CSS section should do the job. I have inserted it into the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <div class="card --linked">
      <h2 class="card__title">title</h2>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque quasi aut deleniti, nisi quo cum, repellendus eius sint consectetur exercitationem aliquid eveniet, eligendi natus neque distinctio omnis consequatur a hic?</p>
      </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

The   .... tag has to be outside the element code in order to make the element attached to the link you want to use

Comment: Your <a> tag is supposed to be outside the element